# How to formulate as an assignment problem?

Tags: operations-research

[image]

How will I formulate this problem as an assignment problem?

I really don't know.

By definition of assignment problem, all the variables $x_{ij}$ are binary $(0$ or $1)$ and all the  supply and demand are equal to $1.$

Will the 'cost' be represented by 'times in seconds' ?

Please someone help me how to solve this, how to translate this table into assignment problem?

I know how to solve the assignment problem, with the Hungarian method, but I did not see any examples like 8.3-4 in class..

Comment: What are the decisions you are making? What can you assign to what?

Comment: @ConMan To assign different swimmers to different strokes.

Comment: So therefore your assignments are "Swimmer X is swimming stroke Y"? And if your objective is "minimise the sum of times", then the costs must therefore be times.

Comment: Why the downvote.. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can see that there are more swimmers than the number of swimming strokes.

We can introduce another dummy swimming stroke that cost time $0$ for everyone. Hence now we have a square table and we can perform Hungarian method to solve the problem.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
           37.7 &   32.9 &   33.8 &   37  & 35.4 \\ \hline
           43.4 &   33.1 & 42.2 & 34.7 & 41.8\\ \hline
33.3 & 28.5 & 38.9 & 30.4 & 33.6 \\ \hline
29.2 & 26.4 & 29.6 & 28.5 & 31.1 \\ \hline
0 & 0  & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
\end{array}

Subtracting the minimum of each row from each row and then subtract the minimum of each column from each column and then cover up the zero (using color blue).

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
           4.8 &   \color{blue}0 &   0.9 &   4.1  & 2.5 \\ \hline
           10.3 &   \color{blue}0 & 9.1 & 1.6 & 8.7\\ \hline
4.8  & \color{blue}0 & 10.4 & 1.9 & 5.1 \\ \hline
2.8 & \color{blue}0 & 3.2 & 2.1 & 4.7 \\ \hline
\color{blue}0 & \color{blue}0  & \color{blue}0 & \color{blue}0 & \color{blue}0 \\ \hline
\end{array}

We then shift the zero and repeat the procedure:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
           3.9 &   \color{blue}0 &   \color{blue}0 &   3.2  & 1.6 \\ \hline
           9.4 &   \color{blue}0 & \color{blue}{8.2} & 0.7 & 7.8\\ \hline
3.9 &   \color{blue}0 & \color{blue}{9.5} & 1 & 4.2\\ \hline
1.9 &   \color{blue}0 & \color{blue}{2.3} & 1.2 & 3.8\\ \hline
\color{blue}0 & \color{blue}{0.9}  & \color{blue}0 & \color{blue}0 & \color{blue}0 \\ \hline
\end{array}

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
           3.2 &   \color{blue}0 &   \color{blue}0 &   \color{blue}{2.5}  & 0.9 \\ \hline
           8.7 &   \color{blue}0 & \color{blue}{8.2} & \color{blue}{0} & 7.1\\ \hline
3.2 &   \color{blue}0 & \color{blue}{9.5} & \color{blue}{0.3} & 3.5\\ \hline
1.2 &   \color{blue}0 & \color{blue}{2.3} & \color{blue}{0.5} & 3.1\\ \hline
\color{blue}0 & \color{blue}{1.6}  & \color{blue}{0.7} & \color{blue}0 & \color{blue}0 \\ \hline
\end{array}

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
           \color{blue}{2.3} &   \color{blue}0 &   \color{blue}0 &   \color{blue}{2.5}  & \color{blue}0 \\ \hline
           \color{blue}{7.8} &   \color{blue}0 & \color{blue}{8.2} & \color{blue}{0} & \color{blue}{6.2}\\ \hline
2.3 &   \color{blue}0 & 9.5 & 0.3 & 2.6\\ \hline
0.3 &   \color{blue}0 & 2.3 & 0.5 & 2.2\\ \hline
\color{blue}0 & \color{blue}{2.5}  & \color{blue}{1.6} & \color{blue}{0.9} & \color{blue}0 \\ \hline
\end{array}

I indicate the selected position in red color.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
           2.3 &   0.3 &   \color{red}0 &   2.5  & 0 \\ \hline
           7.8 &   0.3 & 8.2 & \color{red}{0} & 6.2\\ \hline
2 &   \color{red}0 & 9.2 & 0 & 2.3\\ \hline
\color{red}0 &   0 & 2 & 0.2 & 1.9\\ \hline
0 & 2.8  & 1.6 & 0.9 & \color{red}0 \\ \hline
\end{array}

Hence Carl should do freestyle $(29.2)$, Chris should do butterfly $(28.5)$, David should do backstroke $(33.8)$, Tony should do breaststroke $(34.7)$. The total time by the team is $126.2$.

Let's check our final answer by $R$ software:

```
library(lpSolve)
n <- 5
f.obj <- c(c(37.7, 32.9, 33.8, 37, 35.4, 43.4, 33.1, 42.2, 34.7, 41.8, 33.3, 28.5, 38.9, 30.4, 33.6, 29.2, 26.4, 29.6, 28.5, 31.1), rep(0,n))
f.con<- rbind( kronecker(diag(n), t(rep(1,n))), kronecker(t(rep(1,n)), diag(n)), -diag(n*n))
f.dir <- c(rep('=', n), rep('<=', n*(n+1)))
f.rhs <- c(rep(1,2*n), rep(0,n*n))
optimum <- lp(direction = "min", objective.in = f.obj, const.mat = f.con, const.dir = f.dir, const.rhs = f.rhs)
Success: the objective function is 126.2 
matrix(optimum$solution, nrow = n, byrow = TRUE)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    1    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    1    0
[3,]    0    1    0    0    0
[4,]    1    0    0    0    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    1
```

Comment: In the first part, should be more swimmers than swimming strokes?

Comment: oops, i made a mistake, yup, you are right. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As you have said, the assignment is $x_{ij} = 1$ if swimmer $i$ is assigned to stroke $j$, with $\forall i, j\sum_{j'} x_{ij'} = \sum_{i'} x_{i'j} = 1$ (since we want exactly one swimmer per stroke).

We are trying to get the minimum sum of times, meaning that our objective function is $\sum_{ij} x_{ij} t_{ij}$ where $t_{ij}$ is the time it takes for swimmer $i$ to swim stroke $j$, hence the time is indeed our cost.

Comment: In this solution, won't there be a square table ?

Comment: Why did you write the ' here $\forall i, j\sum_{j'} x_{ij'} = \sum_{i'} x_{i'j} = 1$ ?, notice it's not defined $j'$ nor $i'$

Comment: That's because they're summation variables. I mean that for any fixed $i$, the sum across the $j$s is 1 (i.e. each swimmer swims exactly one stroke). Since I wanted to squash both the sum over $i$ and the sum over $j$ into one statement, I couldn't use $i$ as the summation variable.

Comment: And yes, there will be a square table of decisions.

Comment: ok I understood the summation part.

Comment: How will the table be?